# Odd database error: Empty values?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm creating an activity that views a record and displays it's data to a user to modify. After everything is done just click a button to save the data back into the database. However, once saving time comes around I get an unusual "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values" error. I think it's a SQL code error on my end, but I don't know enough about SQL to find it. Can I get a couple of eyes to see what I did wrong?

Thanks
~Aedon

Here is where the save button is declared and the listener is set. mBoundService is the service that hosts the database and it's calls. DevicesTable is a class that holds the table and column names. DevicesTable.gt_fields[0] is autoincrementID and then serial, name, and first seen columns

```
public void init() {        
    mDevName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dv_name);
    mCurReads = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dv_readings);
    mSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dv_save);
        mSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mBoundService.updateRecord(DevicesTable.gt_name, mId, DevicesTable.g_fields[2], mDevName.getText().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

And this is the database call itself.

```
/**
 * Updates a record at the given table with the given record.
 * @param table The table to update
 * @param id The id of the actual record. Do not pass the incorrect id!
 * @param column The column in which the data is changing
 * @param data The data that is to be changed to
 */
public void updateRecord(String table, String id, String column, String data) {
    mDB.update(table, null, "SET " + column + " = '" + data + "',", new String[]{"id=" + id});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in a `ContentValues` object to tell the database what values go in what columns in the updated row(s).  The strings in the third and fourth arguments make up a `WHERE` clause that indicate what row(s) should be updated.  For example:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("foo", 123);
values.put("bar", 456);

db.update("some_table", values, "id=789", null);
```

This would be equivalent to issuing the query

```
UPDATE some_table SET foo = 123, bar = 456 WHERE id = 789
```

Your code attempts to stuff the entire query into the `WHERE` clause, and `update()` stops you in your tracks because the `values` argument is `null`.

Comment: I see thank you, I was looking at wrong. I thought the documentation was saying that ContentValues was optional and I could do it through string manipulation via the WHERE statement.

Comment: You were probably thinking of something along the lines of `db.rawQuery("UPDATE some_table SET foo = ?, bar = ?  WHERE id = ?", new String[] {"123", "456", "789"})`.